# Why is a template concept allowing CClass&(CUnrelatedClass&) in C++20?

Tags: c++

I've created a C++ concept that checks if a templated class, `T`, is constructible from a fixed class, `CData&`.

For a particular `T = CThing` that **is not** constructible from `CData&`, my concept appears to passing for a reference to that class, i.e. `T = CThing&`, which is not what I want since it results in incorrect template resolution for me.

Not only that, but I'm at a loss as to why this code even compiles, since it successfully initialises the `CThing&` reference from the reference `CData&`, which is a completley unrelated class.

I've included a MWE below to show what I mean.

To my knowledge:

- `return T(data);` should be impossible when `T` is `CThing&` and data is `CData&`, but this is working.
- Concept `IsConstructable` should fail for `CThing&`, but it passes.
- `std::cout << thing.Value` shouldn't even be reached, but it is called (and produces garbage output).

Could someone explain what is going on?

```
#include <iostream>

struct CThing { int Value; };
struct CData { };

template <typename T> concept IsConstructable = requires(CData& data, T t) { T(data); };

template<typename T> struct CSerialiser {};

template <IsConstructable T>
struct CSerialiser<T>
{
    static T Deserialise(CData& data)
    {
        return T(data); 
    };
};

int main()
{
    CData data;
    CThing& thing = CSerialiser<CThing&>::Deserialise(data);
    std::cout << thing.Value; // garbage out
}
```

In response to Weijun Zhou's answer, below, I note that the equivalent non-templated code behaves as expected and does not compile:

```
CData data;
CData& refData;
CThing& thing(refData); // error C2440
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is yet another case why C-style and function-style cast is bad.

`T(data)` with `T=CThing&` and data of type `CData&` of course compiles, because you are doing a `reinterpret_cast` here.

If you want to say `T` should be constructible from `data` or whatever, use the standard concept provided by the library: `std::constructible_from`. Don't roll your own. The standard considers edge cases that you may fail to consider.

And if you have to roll your own, start from the reference implementation on cppreference instead of from scratch.

Comment: Thanks. I know about the C-style cast, but I wasn't aware that a function-style cast could become a `reinterpret_cast`. Why is `T(data)` permitted, while `CThing&(data)` is not?

Comment: Function-style cast is, as the name indicates, function-style and a valid identifier is required at the position corresponding to the "function-name" part. `CThing&` is not a valid identifier, so the **expression** `CThing&(data)` is never parsed as a function-style cast. Instead, it is parsed as operator `&` between `CThing` and `(data)` and since `CThing` is not a valid operand it is ill-formed. For example gcc would complain "Expected primary expression". Note that `CThing&(data)` in other contexts may be treated as a declaration instead, but not here in the context of concepts.

Comment: Quote cppreference: The functional-style cast expression consists of a simple type specifier or a typedef specifier (in other words, a single-word type name). It is also mentioned that function-style cast with a single parameter is equivalent to C-style cast and therefore can perform `reinterpret_cast`.